Finding area using green's theorem
A friend of mine gave me a variant of the goat problem, which is the following: If a goat is tied to a circular fence of radius $10$ feet with a rope of $20$ feet, how much land can the goat roam? I split the roaming land into two parts: a semicircle of radius $20$ and two equivalent irregular shapes. The area of the semicircle is obviously $200\pi$, so the question was to find the area of this shape:

The parametric equations necessary here are $p(t)=10(\cos(t)-(2-t)\sin(t), \sin(t)+(2-t)\cos(t))$, $q(t)=10(\cos(t),\sin(t))$, and $x=10$ when $0<y<20$. To compute the area, I wanted to use Green's theorem, so by splitting the integral so that I'd be calculating along the three separate curves, we get $$A=\int_0^2(f(t)g'(t)-f'(t)g(t))dt+\int_0^210dt+\int_0^{20}10dt$$. The first integral is the line integral along the path $p(t)$, the second along $q(t)$, and the last for $r(t)$. The integrands were of the form $(-b(t),a(t))\cdot(a'(t),b'(t))$, where $(a(t),b(t))$ is the parametric equation given (following this). My issue here is that Desmos says this integral is equivalent to around $487$, but as can be seen in the graph the area of the shape must be less than $200$. What did I do wrong? I'm thinking that maybe the direction of the curve is where I messed up, but this simply just means that I must change the signs of the integrals. If I changed the sign for the integral along the line, we get something around $87$ which is smaller than $100$. This isn't true as can be visualized on the graph. Changing the value of the integral along the irregular arc turns the integral into something around $-47$, and the absolute value of that is still not greater than $100$. Changing the sign of the integral for the circle doesn't affect the value much.
Relevant calculations: For the circle, $(-b(t),a(t))\cdot(a'(t),b'(t))$ reduces to $10(-\sin(t),\cos(t))\cdot(-\sin(t),\cos(t))=10$. For the line, $(-b(t),a(t))\cdot(a'(t),b'(t))$ reduces to $(-t,10)\cdot(0,1)=10$.
Edit: Thanks to whpowell, the actual value was supposed to be around $223$, but this is still bigger than $200$ which means it's still wrong. I think all that's remaining is some incorrect calculation I made in the dot products, which I can't spot.


Your integrals should be halved. The correct formula is $A = \frac{1}{2}\oint_C x~dy-y~dx$. 2. The orientation of $q(t)$ is backwards.


@whpowell96 Thank you for your comment, it does make the area much smaller. But the answer still seems wrong, see the edit.

I get $400/3$ when I do the (correct) integration. You should edit to include the details of your calculation.

@TedShifrin Please make this into an answer, I will be able to find my mistake when you do so. All I did was to use these dot products and substitute them into the integrals, so I'm not sure what I did wrong.

Your parametric equations are correct, but you must be careful to go around the contour counterclockwise. Then (factoring out the factor of $100$ for simplicity):
\begin{align*}
\frac{\text{area}}{50}&= \int_0^2 \left[{-}\big(\sin t+(2-t)\cos t\big)\big({-}\sin t -(2-t)\cos t + \sin t\big)\right. \\&  \qquad + \left.\big(\cos t-(2-t)\sin t)(\cos t - (2-t)\sin t-\cos t\big)\right]dt - \int_0^2 dt + \int_0^2 dt \\
&= \int_0^2 \left[-(\sin t+(2-t)\cos t)({-}(2-t)\cos t)+(\cos t-(2-t)\sin t)(-(2-t)\sin t)\right] dt \\
&= \int_0^2 (2-t)^2\,dt = \int_0^2 t^2\,dt = \frac83.
\end{align*}
Thus, the area is $400/3$, as promised. :)

Now I know what I got wrong, I forgot to multiply the $10$'s together when calculating the integral of the circle. Thanks!
